# Windows 10 Mouse/Touchscreen event log

Tags: windows, events, operating-system, viewer, event-viewer

Unable to find Windows 10 Event Log for mouse/touch.  Any log that indicates activity upon touching a computer that is always on has no logon screen, and the main application is always open.  Similar to a kiosk.

Will be using Zabbix (Network Monitoring) to monitor the log file for activity(Modifications, or maybe Some text parse).

Comment: There will be no such event log out of the box. Imagine the number of events. You will need to write or find a program that logs such events for you in a smart way that exactly fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

ended up writing my own python script for my needs..  I hope this helps someone else

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref
import time

class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_long)]

while True:
    #Get x coordinate of cursor
    def queryCursorPosition1():
        pt = POINT()
        windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
        return { "x": pt.x}
    pos1 = queryCursorPosition1()

    #Get x coordinate of cursor a few seconds later
    time.sleep(1)
    def queryCursorPosition2():
        pt = POINT()
        windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
        return { "x": pt.x}
    pos2 = queryCursorPosition2()

    #Print movement 'detected' if x coord do not match past x coord
    if pos1 != pos2:
        print("Movement Detected")
        print(pos1)
        print(pos2)
        print("---")


        f= open("track.txt","w+")
        f.write("X1: %s X2: %s" % (pos1, pos2))
```